Continuous, modulated wave for sx1276 for FCC testing for LORA
I am getting ready to bring an electronic device using SX1276 Lora radio to market. The FCC testing lab has requested that I be able to put the radio into the following configuration:

100% Duty Cycle modulated signal with 500 kHz BW

I cannot figure out how to do a Lora modulated signal (with 500 khz BW) at a 100% duty cycle.
The best I can do so far is:

a 100% duty cycle/continuous signal with FSK modulation (bandwidth is not 500khz, no lora settings, etc). I can do this by using this code: https://github.com/StuartsProjects/SX12XX-LoRa/blob/master/examples/SX127x_examples/Basics/80_Direct_DIO2_Tone/80_Direct_DIO2_Tone.ino

a lora modulated signal with correct parameters that is NOT 100% duty cycle. I have to send packets in a loop and the signal/wave is "bursty" because of this. I can do this using this code with zero delay between loop iterations: https://github.com/StuartsProjects/SX12XX-LoRa/blob/master/examples/SX127x_examples/Basics/103_Lora_Transmitter_Detailed_Setup/103_Lora_Transmitter_Detailed_Setup.ino


How can I get a continuous, Lora modulated signal with lora settings (bandwidth, sf, etc) that has a 100% duty cycle?
Thank you

Question: you're not using a radio module that is pre-certified, so to avoid having to certify the whole device, right?

I have a pre-certified module. The lab is requesting this for emissions testing
